# is this sentence correct? the company are going to send me there next week

Tags: grammar

i would like to reply to your letter, which arrived two days ago, before leaving for Rome i was told yesterday that the company **are going to send me** there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just focussing on the part of the sentence mentioned in the title (there are other problems with it):

In British usage, this is perfectly fine.

In American usage, people who believe there is such a thing as "correct" usually object to this and say it should be *is going to*.

Comment: the choices are: 1. shall have sent         2. are going to send                     3. shall be sending                                  4. shall send

Comment: I know of no variety of English in which _the company shall ..._ is grammatical, except in the sense of putting a requirement on the company. With _will_ instead of _shall_ these are grammatical; but I cannot think of a context in which your choice 1 would make sense.